# ListInstance deployment guid problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a very basic setup, currently, and I'm fairly new to Sharepoint. I followed the walkthrough [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx) to create a Field definition, content type, list definition from the content type, and a list instance from that list definition.

Currently, if I attempt to deploy my feature with everything in it, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
```

The feature doesn't show up in the administration panel, but the list instance is created (but has no fields because the custom content type isn't activated).

If I remove the listinstance from the feature, everything else activates just fine, and if I put the listinstance in a separate feature it still works, but this really all needs to be in one feature and I don't understand why it doesn't work that way. I added a guid to the list instance that was auto generated because I need to reference this list in the rest of the feature's code. This is the list instance's Elements.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="SurveyModule - SurveyList"
                Id="{C0ED4B73-B140-4057-989B-43344CEE921E}"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="10000"
                Url="Lists/SurveyModule-SurveyList"
                Description="My List Instance">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

If there are any other code snippets which would be relevant I can post them.

Answer (score 0):

try it without the braces in the id attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="SurveyModule - SurveyList"
                Id="C0ED4B73-B140-4057-989B-43344CEE921E"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="10000"
                Url="Lists/SurveyModule-SurveyList"
                Description="My List Instance">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

if it still doesn't work, generate a new GUID using: Visual Studio - Tools - Generate GUID (Registry)

Comment: Convention in Sharepoint is to have the braces around the Guids, that's what I have for all my other custom pieces. I've tried a few different guids, as well as no guid (which is the default) and nothing works. I even tried it without the braces to no avail.

Like I said, if they are in separate features they deploy just fine and my code can reference the list instance using the assigned guid, they just have problems coexisting in the same feature. (And I already checked to ensure the guid wasn't being used elsewhere).

Comment: sounds like a very weird behavior... do you mind sending me your solution so i can have a closer look?

Comment: I deleted and recreated the ListDefinition, gave it an entirely new GUID, and the problem persisted. I checked the schema.xml of the ListDefinition and the autogenerated Field Id value was the GUID in lower-case whereas the FieldReference Id was the GUID in upper-case. While this shouldn't make a difference, I changed it to upper-case and it deployed properly. When I changed it back to lower-case, it continued to deploy properly. Sharepoint is weird. Since my solution is now fixed, I can't continue to troubleshoot it to figure out what was really wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the SharePoint Madness ;-)